# background image does not show up with no-repeat

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm trying to place a small icon inside the ValidationSummary div (to the left of the bullet list). The image shows up, but with repeat when I use:

```
background:url(Images/exclamation.png);
```

The image does not show at all, when I say:

```
background:url(Images/exclamation.png) no-repeat 12px 30px;
```

What am I missing here.

CSS:

```
 .validationsummary
  {
   background:url(Images/exclamation.png) no-repeat 12px 30px;
   border:1px solid #b08b38;
   width:99%;    
  }
 .validationsummary ul
 {  
  color:#982b12;
  background-color:PeachPuff;
 }
.validationsummary ul li
 {
 padding:2px 0px 0px 15px; 
 font-size:12px;   
 }
```

ASPX:

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td width="100%">
   <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" CssClass="validationsummary" 
    DisplayMode="BulletList" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="10px">        
 <tr>
  <td width="11%" align="left">
   * Surname
  </td>
  <td width="18%" align="left">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Width="93%"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"  
     ControlToValidate="txtSurname" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"  
     Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Surname Is Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just use "background-repeat: none;" below "background".

Comment: Have you tried `no-repeat` without the positioning attributes? You could potentially be moving it off-screen.

Comment: Also, how large is the validationsummary on the screen?

Comment: Im using css3.0.It doesnt have 'none' for background-repeat. I tried with 0 0 as the attributes. Have not set any height for the validation summary.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.validationsummary
{
   background:url(Images/exclamation.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   border:1px solid #b08b38;
   width:99%;    
}
```

If it is working, position your background accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

background-image:url('Images/exclamation.png');

background-repeat-x: no-repeat;

background-repeat-y: no-repeat;

Comment: This property was unavailable. Were you referring to background-repeat:repeat-x no-repeat; That did not work either

Answer (score 0):

Also define the height of your background image

```
.validationsummary
  {
   background:url(Images/exclamation.png) no-repeat 12px 30px;
   border:1px solid #b08b38;
   width:99%;   

    height: 200px; /* change it with your requirement */


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.validationsummary
{
    background-image: url('Images/exclamation.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top; 
    background-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px; /* Depends on the size of the image - 16px + 4px actual padding to indent the text to the right of the image */
}
```